# Nginx Reverse-Proxy Configuration Issue: Rewrite or Internal Redirection Cycle with VueJS SPA and GraphQL Backend

Tags: vue.js, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an application that serves the backend (GraphQL API) aswell as the frontend (VueJS SPA) on one endpoint:

- `/graphql` => Backend endpoint (no further routes needed here)
- `/` => SPA (index.html, History-Routing)

The SPA is using History-Routing. This means, that the views are reached by common URL's like:

- `/login`
- `/dashboard`
- etc.

This application aswell as the nginx webserver are running in a docker container and can reach each other. For the nginx server i have the following configuration:

```
server {
    listen      4430 ssl;
    server_name myapp.mydomain.ch;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.mydomain.ch/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.mydomain.ch/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass                      http://myhost:10000/;
        proxy_set_header Host           $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP      $remote_addr;
        try_files                       $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /graphql {
        proxy_pass                      http://myhost:10000/graphql;
        proxy_set_header Host           $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP      $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

This works fine so far. The application can be used at `myapp.mydomain.ch`. But if i refresh a page with an existing route or redirect to o specific view/path, the webserver returns the following error:

```
nginx      | 2023/12/27 14:09:27 [error] 20#20: *6 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 81.62.132.74, server: myapp.mydomain.ch, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "myapp.mydomain.ch", referrer: "https://myapp.mydomain.ch/login"
```

As I understood this, this should always return the index.html if a route is not found which would be ok as the SPA can then handle the routing.

I tried to change the nginx configuration in several ways. Example: If i use the following configuration:

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass                      http://myhost:10000/;
        proxy_set_header Host           $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP      $remote_addr;
    }
```

The application works fine too. If i refresh i get a HTTP 404 instead. Which seems logic as the reverse proxy cannot handle the routing.

Does anyone have an idea what im doing wrong or how the nginx config should look like with my setup?